# Is it haraam to watch images of anime that are semi naked?

Tags: halal-haram, image, cartoon

Is watching anime images, but not the series or any inappropriate moves they do, sinful and haram?

Is it haram even if you think it wouldn't lead you to any haram things or to watching inappropriate images of real persons?

Comment: I personally believe it's same as video games. It isn't real so. No sin as committed. Same as we kill people in video gsmes.

Answer (score 1):

Anything which leads you to watch some inappropriate images or videos or may bring you to do inappropriate move, is a sin and also affect your life circumstances badly.

Answer (score 0):

Hormah (being haram) of looking at others with the intention of pleasure and lust is a general rule. There is no difference between film and animation and so on. Even if a man looks at his homosexual with the intention of sexual pleasure, he has committed a sin.

Reference: https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa21586

Answer (score -1):

My personal opinion,
If you know the show is about lewd and edgy then yes, like high school DxD or other highly nude anime. But shows like naruto and other who have some episodes with nudes in them (usually blurry or covered) are is no way haram.

Read what the show is about is there are tags like, lewd or naked try to avoid them if you can.